# Number of transactions in auto-renewable subscriptions Sandbox

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscriptions, auto-renewing

Apple [documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html) states:

> When testing auto-renewable subscriptions in the test environment, keep in mind that the duration times are compressed. Additionally, test subscriptions only auto-renew a maximum of six times.

When I do restore I get all transactions, often there are less than 6 transactions for a single subscription. Sometimes I get lets say transactions 1-3, 4-5 are missing and 6 is present too.

My implementation of subscriptions requires giving access only to content covered by subscription's date range. I'm totally confused if it's a bug in Sandbox?

Do you guys have the same experience? I'm confused how to test this stuff properly. Do I need to provide to my tester log of all restored (in that case) transactions so he will be able to say "Yes, everything is fine as we didnt received transactions x, y and z"?

**Basically: Are you always getting exactly 6 transactions for auto-renewable subscriptions in Sandbox?**

Comment: So your problem is: when you restore you don't get all transactions?

Comment: Yes, and I'm not sure if something is wrong, if you guys have similar experiences, and finally how to test it

Comment: I'm curious if you are running under iOS7? Or earlier?

Comment: Yes @ChrisPrince, I'm on iOS 7

Comment: How are you determining that you are not getting all the transactions in the restore? Is this on the device side or your server side? Can you post an example iOS7 receipt in your question above, possibly in JSON and explain what is missing? Are you certain all of your transactions have been processed through your transaction observer?

Comment: @ChrisPrince yes, all transactions are processed through transaction observer.